# how to deploy a site if you have a domain

Tags: reactjs, deployment, dns, github-pages, netlify

I have a portfolio website built using React .I already know what to do if I want to deploy using github pages or other sites like Netlify  I am wondering what I am supposed to do if I have my own domain so I can deploy to Netlify

Comment: Point the domain to the server you are using to host.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex issue. Try digging into git based deployments. I can see that Netlify supports this but maybe [their docs](https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/overview/) ain't the best explanation for starters.

Maybe this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIvDWeTXbQk) explains it better but that's just my random find.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can you just have to add your own custom domain while you deploying your app using Netlify
I have find this website to explain how you can:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-host-domain-to-netlify-site-for-free-step-by-step-guide-45d0c2102db3?gi=bacd2d1b29c3